# Windows Scheduler with local system account

Tags: scheduled-task

I'm trying to schedule a windows scheduler job on Windows 2008 R2 using a Local System Account of another box.

Could anyone please tell me whether this is possible?

Scenario:

> 1. I've Server A where windows scheduler will be scheduled.
> 2. This scheduler needs to create/delete/get files located at SERVER
>      B. This SERVER B is located on different domain.
> 3. I'm trying to schedule the Windows Scheulder on SERVER A with Local Account on
>      SERVER B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a job that will have access to both server a and server b, you must have a set of credentials that exist on both a and b.  This can be a duplicate local account (same name/password on both machines), or a domain account.  If across two domains, there must be a trust relationship in place between the two domains.

Comment: Thanks D.K, I'm trying with first Mapping the the remote drive and using the mapped drive. It seems to work only when the account that the user that schedule task is running is LOGGED ON TO THE Machine where Schedule Task is running?

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it, I'd make sure that you're using the correct username in the job.  i.e., try [COMPUTERNAME]\username.

Answer (score 0):

The Local System account is restricted to the local system, hence the name. You can't use it on another system. Nor can you use the Local System account on one machine from another, at least not without a bunch of trickery that involves at least one other account.